# Populate table on combo box selection using SWT/Jface

Tags: java, data-binding, swt, jface, tableviewer

Is there any way to populate table viewer on combo box value selection using SWT/Jface databinding?

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done. Can you post an isolated code snipped indicating exactly where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You will not use JFace databinding with this solution but I hope you will find what you want :

Use a `ComboViewer` with your `TableViewer` and do something like :

```
comboViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
         tableViewer.setInput(event.getSelection());
         tableViewer.refresh();
    }
});
```